# Scroll webView with volume keys

Tags: android, webview, scroll, keyevent

How do you scroll a webView w/ the volume hard keys? ...and can it be done with easing?  If so, how?  I'm a nooB to Android - Coming over from ActionScript and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
my R.id.webPg001 is a WebView id.
```

This is where I'm at now:

```
@Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
      ScrollView scrollView;
      scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.webPg001);        
          switch (keyCode) {
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
              if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                  scrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
                  scrollView.computeScroll(); 
              }
              return true;
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
              if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          scrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                  scrollView.computeScroll(); 
              }
              return true;
          default:
              return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
          }
      }
```

Comment: P.S. I need the view to scroll a screen length. ie: like when you use the page up/dwn keys on the keyboard of a desk top. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct code: (thnx NdrU!!)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    WebView scrollView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ch01);     
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                scrollView.pageUp(false);   
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                scrollView.pageDown(false);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

WebView has methods `pageUp` and `pageDown`, according to the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pageDown%28boolean%29), they scroll half a page, so you will probably want to call them twice to get a full page scroll.

As to the code you have, I thought the preffered way to listen to button presses is by overriding `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` methods, but I might be wrong (I'm new to android development myself).

Comment: Thanx. I was looking into that b4 the post but I couldn't get it written correctly.  Any way you can shoot me an example?  Thanx again for your support.

Comment: First you need to obtain a reference to the WebView, so change the two lines before the switch statement to `WebView scrollView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webPg001);`, next, delete the two lines where you call `pageScroll` and `computeScroll`, and put `scrollView.pageUp(false);` twice instead (or `pageDown`, of course).

Comment: THANX!!  Works beautifully.  I tried something similar to that but not quite there.  Thanx for your help - That was too easy (not 4 me yet, but I'll catch on. LOL).

Comment: One more ? if you don't mind: How can I implement this as a class (or a short-hand way) so it can be used for all WebViews w/o having to rewrite over and over again for each WebView? The nxt WebView id is "webPg02" and so on... nested within my VeiwFlipper with id "AC4313".  Thanx again for the help above.

Comment: That really depends on the rest of your code, but I understand that you have several WebView in a single activity. In that case, I would personally keep track of which WebView is currently visible and than switch on that value and select the appropriate WebView where you do `WebView scrollView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ch01);`. If you have multiple activities each having one WebView, I would create a common abstract superclass that overrides `dispatchKeyEvent` and have all my activities extend this new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're not aware, the normal mechanism for navigation is to use the arrow keys or trackball for hardware-level navigation.  Your webviews should plug in to this mechanism with no additional effort on your part, and so unless you have a clear application-specific reason for tapping into the volume keys, I would recommend using the built-in functionality here.

Comment: Thnx for the info but, most Android devices no longer have a trackball nor do they have "arrow keys"(except for the ones w/Hard-boards).  You navigate via gestures.  If you haven't noticed, most android browsers also navigate up/down using the volume hard keys (ie: Opera). I am developing for the Galaxy Tab (it uses the volume keys as the 'arrow keys').  I have found several resources on this subject for navigation in WebView, but are lacking the code (I) needed to implement the hard keys.