# Scroll webView with volume keys Part II

Tags: android, android-webview, keyevent

Related to the thread: [Scroll webView with volume keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949427/scroll-webview-with-volume-keys/4951477#4951477)

How can I implement this as a class (or a short-hand way) so it can be used for all WebViews w/o having to rewrite over and over again for each WebView? The nxt WebView id's are "webPg02", "webPg03", and so on... All nested within my VeiwFlipper with id "AC4313".

I'm sure this is really basic but once again thanks for helping this Android nooB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `onKeyDown()` in your activity and apply the button presses to the current `WebView`.